# Change the colour of multiple links when hover over one link

Tags: css, html

I want to change the colour of three links when I hover over a one link.

- Can I do that in html and css?
- If so, how can I do that?
- Is there any way that I can use a class inside class method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)?

Comment: You need to show a code snippet of what you already have tried. The question might be too broad now. SO is **NOT** a code writing service

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help us help you, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use the `hover` pseudo selector within CSS to accomplish this effect. 2) Place the hover selector on the parent of the child links. 3) You can replace `a` with a `.link` class, but that's up to you.

```css
.links a {
  color: #333;
}

.links:hover a {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <a href="#">link 2</a>
  <a href="#">link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the exact code I have been searching. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

1 & 2: No you can't currently do that in plain HTML and CSS in any way that I'm aware of. In the future you may be able to, however, using the `:has` selector. See this little code snippet for a quick demo of how:

```css
p > a {
  color: blue;
}

p:has(a:hover) a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph the contains some blue <a>links</a>. There are a few different <a>links</a> in here. You can hover over any of the <a>links</a>, and in a browser which supported the :has CSS selector, all of the <a>links</a> would have the hover styles applied to them and turn red.</p>
```

Note that the `:has` query selector is currently experimental, and as of this writing support is limited to use "with functions like `document.querySelector()`" and it "can not be used within stylesheets" (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) for more info). (So, to be clear, the above snippet should not function until browsers support the :has selector, I've just included it to demonstrate how the :has selector would address this use case.)

3: The third question is not clear enough for me to answer it.